# Why were my suggested git-core tag wiki edits rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, rejected-edits, tag-wiki-excerpt

I was just looking through the tags on Stack Overflow and saw that the wikis for some of them were empty, like [git-core](/questions/tagged/git-core).

So I decided to help this site by adding a [tag excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2675416) and [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2675415). However, since I do not have enough reputation yet, my edit was reviewed by other community members. One person approved it, but a moderator rejected it.

I do not know why my suggested edits were rejected; I believe that the decision was incorrect. I later read through all the tag wiki edit guidelines, but I still do not understand what was wrong with my edits.

The tag is **still blank**, and I provided some important knowledge for it. I am not saying my suggestion was perfect, but I think something is better than nothing. Can anyone please tell me why my suggested edit was rejected?

Comment: Something is not always better than nothing in tag wikis. Your question does not explain why you think that any moderator power was involved at all.

Comment: Pro tip: don't make this a referendum on the actions of a particular moderator, much less moderators in general. Focus instead on *why* your specific suggested edit was rejected, and what you could have done to improve it. That is far more constructive, and is much likely to go in your favor (e.g. attract fewer downvotes).

Comment: But just FYI, I would have approved both of those edits. The excerpt looks to be an accurate description of the tag, and specifies when it should be used on questions. The full wiki also looks OK to me—not perfect, but acceptable, and at least not plagiarized from an external source without attribution.

Comment: How could I improve it, He didn't edited it..... just rejected

Comment: Why i am getting downvotes on this question, Is something wrong with this post

Comment: @CodyGray: the wiki excerpt is rather useless; it explains the `git-core` command, but tag wikis are not meant to be command manuals.

Comment: @VegetarianVulture: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. I'd say that people are voting against the 'moderator abusing his powers' allegations here, you are jumping to conclusions here.

Comment: I tried to explain that already, @Martijn. Too bad it got lost in a sea of whining.

Comment: I made an edit to your title. For this to be at all constructive, the thing to determine here is _why_ those edits were rejected, which is the only thing that can indicate if a _mistake_ might have been made. I really encourage you to edit your question a bit - implying abuse when subjective understanding is at work is not really constructive.

Comment: "git-core is git installer for Linux, ..." That's news to me. Some distros have packages called git-core though. In my opinion your proposed excerpt isn't very clear at all.

Comment: So, Now it's all gone....??? Isn't it ??

Comment: And the only questions tagged `git-core` are for MacOSX. So the description you proposed doesn't match the actual use.

Comment: This was not the first time, I've edited a tag wiki. I've added 3 others before, but this was not a rational decision, I still believe.

Comment: FYI, typically the suggested edits have very good reasons for their rejections. The only tag wiki to date I've tried to create returned two very good custom rejection reasons. Please look through those first in the future!

Answer (score 10):

The [wiki suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2675415) you made doesn't explain the usage of the tag.

It explains `git-core` - that's not what tag wikis are for.

Bullet point 4 of the guidelines:

> Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag

---

Now, re-reading, the problem is that the guidance is buried at the *bottom* of the edit. It should be at the top. As commented here, it should also not be a complete manual for `git-core`.

---

As for the excerpt, it has grammar and accuracy issues.

Comment: Not sure I agree here. That's what the tag wiki *excerpt* is for, to explain the usage of the tag. The blog article you linked to appears to agree with me, because it talks mostly about excerpts. It's perfectly acceptable if the full tag wiki contains generalized information about the tool/technology. His proposed excerpt *did* explain which questions the tag should be used on/with.

Comment: Well, Then I believe he could have done it.

Comment: @CodyGray: That still needs reworking; the tag usage is buried in one little sentence at the bottom. That should be listed at the top instead, and then perhaps some discussion of *common* problems with `git-core`, not a complete manual.

Comment: @CodyGray - The instructions should have been at the _top_ of the edit, not buried at the bottom.

Comment: Is the basic guidance ever something else than "when your question is about this subject"?

Comment: "Buried at the bottom" is a little bit silly when *the whole thing is 3 lines*. I mean, I think it is important for the excerpt to *extremely briefly* define what something is. I don't know what git-core is. I need the excerpt to tell me that. This one appears to do so.

Comment: @CodyGray - I see 50 lines, not 3.

Comment: @CodyGray but do you think is this the only reason he rejected my edit, please take a look at his suggested edit history

Comment: @Oded We are talking about two different things. You are talking about the full wiki, I am talking about the excerpt. The blog post you linked to is *also* talking about the excerpt.

Comment: @CodyGray - I find the excerpt to also have problems. Grammar is not good and actual description not very accurate.